# Mongoose $push to array inside subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a companies model which has payment info stored like this:

```
let paymentSchema = new Schema({
    date: Date,
    chargeId: String
    amount: Number,
    receipt_url: String,
    currency: String,
    type: String
});

 paymentInfo: {
    lastPayment: {type: paymentSchema},
    paymentHistory: [{type: paymentSchema}],
    paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
    customerId: customerId
 }
)};
```

The `paymentInfo` is a subdocument and I am using schema there for some validation purposes.

While trying to update the a company's info using the following query, it updates everything except the `paymentHistory` :

```
Companies.updateOne(
                  {_id: companyId},
                  {
                     paymentInfo: {
                        paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
                        customerId: customerId,
                        lastPayment : paymentObject,
                        $push: {paymentHistory: paymentObject }
                  }
```

One could say why save the same `paymentObject` in `lastPayment` and also push it to `paymentHistory` - that's required for a feature we need and that's not causing any trouble.

I also tried the following update query and it gives a conflict error - `updates` in the following code is a valid object and without `$push` it works fine

```
{$set: updates, $push: {'paymentInfo.paymentHistory': paymentObject}}
```

**Conflict Error :**
`{"driver":true,"name":"MongoError","index":0,"code":40,"errmsg":"Updating the path 'paymentInfo' would create a conflict at 'paymentInfo'"}`

**What do I want?**

I want to update the company document in a single database call - looking at that error it seems like I am supposed to make 2 calls, one for $set and other for $push? Is there anything wrong with the first update query??

**Possible Solution**

One way to solve this is to take out the `paymentHistory` out of `paymentInfo` so that it's part of main company schema - that solves the issue but I want to keep all payment related stuff inside `paymentInfo`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you add the Company schema? Also what are these lines?     `paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
    customerId: customerId`

Comment: There's no point in adding company schema - I've added of the schema I am trying to update and those lines are part of the update query - ```paymentMethod``` and ```customerId``` are part of the payment schema which is an embedded document inside the main company schema.